# Change key baised style in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, styles

I have two styles in two resource dictionaries. When application load then I have loaded one (`Dictionary1.xaml`) resource. After that when I click on button then I want to change style. i.e I want to load `Dictionary2.xaml`. I have changed but there is no effect on my button.

Dictionary1.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="s1">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>  
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> 
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Dictionary2.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="s1">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green</Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

When application load then

```
Uri sUri = new Uri("/KeyCheck;component/Dictionary1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
ResourceDictionary r = new ResourceDictionary();
r.Source = sUri;
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(r);
```

Apply style in page: Main.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource s1}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="195,133,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/> 
</Grid>
```

When click on button then:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri sUri = new Uri("/KeyCheck;component/Dictionary1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    ResourceDictionary r = new ResourceDictionary();
    r.Source = sUri;
    App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(r);

    sUri = new Uri("/KeyCheck;component/Dictionary2.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    r = new ResourceDictionary();
    r.Source = sUri;
    App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(r);
}
```

Comment: If literally all you're wanting to do is change the style of it when clicked than the route you're going is overkill and you should look into building it into a/the `Style` template for a `ToggleButton` (which I kind of assume is what you're looking for really) and add the changes for the `Selected` State in the `VisualStateManager` Or is there actually a reason for trying to switch between two separate resource dictionaries?

Comment: No, By using this concept I want to change my software theme. I have used different key style in my application. But when I want to change my theme then I have seen that there is no effect occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem as described below:

1. At first I have created a class like so:

   ```
   public class ProjectKeys : INotifyPropertyChanged {
       Style styKey = new Style();
       public Style StyKey {
           get {
               return styKey; 
           } set {
               styKey = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged("StyKey"); 
           } 
       }
       protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); 
       }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
   }
   ```

   which contains my all key styles.
2. After that I have created a class which contains `ProjectKeys` type property. This class is inherited by other view model classes.

   ```
   public class VMBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
       public VMBase() { } 
       ProjectKeys styKey = App.AllStyleKeys; 
       public ProjectKeys VMStyKey {
           get { 
               return styKey; 
           } set { 
               styKey = value; 
               NotifyPropertyChanged("VMStyKey"); 
           } 
       }
       protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
           if (PropertyChanged != null) 
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
   }
   ```
3. After that I have inherited above class in my view model

   ```
   Public class VMTest1: VMBase { } 
   Public class VMTest2: VMBase { }
   ```
4. Now I have binded the above two vm in two Views:

   ```
   ViewTest1() {
       //others... 
       this.DataContext = new VMTest1(); 
   }
   ViewTest1() {
       //others... 
       this.DataContext = new VMTest2(); 
   }
   ```
5. After that I have changed in xaml

   ```
   <Button Style="{Binding Path= VMStyKey.StyKey}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click" >
   ```
6. The following code starts the application:

   ```
   private static ProjectKeys _AllStyleKeys = new ProjectKeys();
   public static ProjectKeys AllStyleKeys {
       get {
           return _AllStyleKeys; 
       } set {
           _AllStyleKeys = value; 
       } 
   }
   public App() {
       Uri sUri = new Uri("/KeyCheck;component/Dictionary1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
       ResourceDictionary r = new ResourceDictionary();
       r.Source = sUri;
       Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(r);
       AllStyleKeys.StyKey = (Style)App.Current.Resources["MyKey"]; 
   }
   ```

   7.After changing my style, opened pages, view pages and new pages get the same style.

   ```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
       Uri sUri = new Uri("/KeyCheck;component/Dictionary1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
       ResourceDictionary r = new ResourceDictionary();
       r.Source = sUri;
       App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(r);
       sUri = new Uri("/KeyCheck;component/Dictionary2.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
       r = new ResourceDictionary(); 
       r.Source = sUri; 
       App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(r);
       var Style = App.Current.Resources["MyKey"] as Style;
       App.AllStyleKeys.StyKey = Style; 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing but couldn't get it to work. I got the dictionary to load but coulnd't get it to update to UI, tried everything (re binded & various update UI techniques).

In the end i ended up just changing the value of the static resource at runtime, depending on user selection :

`Application.Current.Resources("Background").Color = HexColor("#FF838383")`

Hex color is a method used to convert hex codes to ARGB

Comment: Thanks, Above my problem is just for getting concept. Actually I need to use it in my project Broadly. Suppose I have five textboxes in my page. But I want to use five styles for my five textboxes in this case I want to use style by key. But when I have changed my theme then key based controls do not work. i.e. there is no effect will occur.

Comment: I see, it would be inappropriate in your case to manually force a change in each element of the style. Well if you find a solution please update your answer as I'd be interested to see how it's done. Maybe researching into forcing a rebind of the controls is the way to go? as the new dictionary has already been loaded

Comment: When you will remove all key related information. i.e remove key from dictionary and page then system will work properly. But when I want use key then system does not work.

Comment: Yea you need the key to bind to the controls, without using keys it's pretty useless

Answer (score 0):

`DynamicResource` binding in Button's style will do the trick.

```
Style="{DynamicResource s1}"
```